# display google Map with an ajax call in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, google-maps

I have a problem in my project about google Maps. When I use an ajax call to display map, it didn't appear. It works normally when I do not use ajax. I don't know if there are problems of synchronisation in Map loading.
Any help please. This is a part of my code:

ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#ModifPlanRoute").dialog("close");
$.ajax({
    url: '/Agent/displayMAP/',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (result) {
        $('#ListeAgent2').html(result);
     }
 });        
</script>
```

view where I want to display the map:

```
@model IEnumerable<PFE.Models.ptVente>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "MapPtVente";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
var waypoints = [];
  </script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 

 @foreach (var item in Model){
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var lat = '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.latitude)'.replace(",", ".");
      var lng = '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.longitude)'.replace(",", ".");

      stop = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      waypoints.push({
          location: stop,
          stopover: true
      });

  </script>
 }

  <script type="text/javascript">
 var map;
 var directionDisplay;
 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

 function initialize() {
     directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.68447108872107, 10.181236267089844);
     var myOptions = {
         zoom: 8,
         center: latlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"),
        myOptions);
     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

     var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(36.85142615835436, 10.147939324378967);
     var destination =  new google.maps.LatLng(36.85142615835436, 10.147939324378967);

     var request = {
     origin: origin,
     destination: destination,         
     waypoints: waypoints,
     travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
     optimizeWaypoints: true,
     avoidHighways: true,
     avoidTolls: true
     };

     directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
     }
     });

   }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

 </script>

 <div id="map2" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the page you are requesting via AJAX contains JavaScript code. You can't dynamically add JavaScript code that needs to be executed to the page in this way. When you request the page via AJAX, you are getting back the HTML and the JavaScript, but the JavaScript isn't being executed.